# Flexible replacement for CInt?

Tags: .net, vb.net, xamarin, type-conversion, portable-class-library

I have some older code that makes extensive use of CInt, CStr and similar. I am in the midst of updating this so we can use PCL on it for Xamarin/Mono targets. Xamarin does not provide these methods (as they are part of the VisualBasic namespace), although normally the underlying methods are provided.

But I am confused as to what PCL-allowed calls actually match these functions. CInt will take a string, another int, a double, practically anything, and return an Integer. But...

- Integer.Parse/TryParse only takes strings, you can't pass in a double, etc
- System.Convert.ToInt16/32/64 seems more flexible, but which is the same as Integer?

Is there a direct replacement for CInt, CDbl, etc?

Comment: Hmm, no, these VB.NET methods are readily available in a PCL project that targets VB.  Hard to guess what you are doing.

Comment: I'm simply running the PCL Analyze Assemble Portability tool on Windows & Xamarin targets. It reports that CInt is not available under Xamarin, so...

Comment: but which is the same as Integer? => Int32 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx

Comment: Hmm, that's just the tip of the iceberg.  All VB.NET runtime support will be missing on an Apple phone.  Xamarin doesn't support VB.NET, you can't call anybody when you have a problem.  You'd better switch to C#.  Limp along with the Convert class, if you have to.

Comment: I am aware of all this Hans, which is why I am asking a very focussed question here. Is there something in Convert or Integer, which ARE in Xamarin, that matches the API of CInt?

Comment: The problem with things like `CInt` and `CStr` is that they can be used to either cast or convert.  There's noting in the Framework itself that does both.  In some cases, the correct replacement would be to use an explicit cast while in others it would be appropriate to use the `Convert` class or the like.  There is no one replacement that will work in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Replacements are :

- ConvertToInt32 is the same as Integer, it will do the job just as CInt(). ConvertToInt64 is for Long and ToInt16 is for small values.
- Casting > int result = (int)value;
  which is casting a value into an int. It's not the same as converting it but it will work on double, floats, long ... if possible.
- Int.Parse, Int.TryParse. As you pointed it earlyer it will only parse a string to convert it on Integer.

Guess that for your need the best choice would be ConvertToInt32.